# Spring boot and JUnit with H2 JPA causes 'pg_class' not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I currently have a spring boot application which contains 2 configuration files: **application.yaml** and **application-test.yaml**. The application-test profile is loaded correctly and any settings in that file are working as expected.

However i am having an issue with one setting in particular which is spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = 'update'. When this setting is defined in the **application.yaml** file it causes my JPA unit tests to fail with the exception "Table "PG_CLASS" not found".
I have tried overriding this setting with different values in the application-test configuration file to no avail.

My full configuration files are as follows:

**application.yaml**

```
#Configure Postgres backend datasource
spring.datasource.driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-75-233-146.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/xxxx?user=xxxx&password=xxxxx&sslmode=require
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

**application-test.yaml**

```
spring.datasource.usernam: sa
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:mem:tests;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.datasource.driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_default: false
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2
```

Uncommenting the "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update" setting in my application.yaml file does fix the issue. But i would like to keep this enabled. Any ideas?

Comment: In most cases you don't want that setting to be enabled in production as databases in production are managed through various entities like DBA or support etc. If you are controlling the database schema update, try to integrate liquibase or Flyway or similar tools for database migration instead of depending on JPA tooling

Answer (score 4):

The above errror seems to be caused by Hibernate using the wrong dialect (PostgreSQL instead of H2).

Maybe try adding the following in application-test.yaml:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

These properties worked for me.

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

spring.datasource.usernam: sa
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:mem:tests;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```